# C# IE.ShowBrowserBar not working

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

I used C# to navigate to a new page with IE. I want to hide explorer bar(Ctrl+Shift+i) if it was shown in advance. But the code is not working. Here is the code:

```
IWebBrowser2 IE = new InternetExplorer();
IE.ToolBar = 0;
IE.Resizable = false;
SetForegroundWindow(IE.HWND);
string CLSID_Favorites = "{EFA24E61-B078-11D0-89E4-00C04FC9E26E}";
string CLSID_History = "{EFA24E62-B078-11D0-89E4-00C04FC9E26E}";
string CLSID_Channels = "{EFA24E63-B078-11D0-89E4-00C04FC9E26E}";
// not working
IE.ShowBrowserBar(CLSID_Favorites, false, 0);
IE.ShowBrowserBar(CLSID_History, false, 0);
IE.ShowBrowserBar(CLSID_Channels, false, 0);
```

Can someone please tell why? Many thanks.